# JSF1029 warning during deploying on a server

Tags: jsf

I use JSF 2.1.21 and Tomahawk 1.1.14. And when I try to deploy my project on a server(it can be Tomcat or Weblogic) I see the Warnings:

```
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version
 of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class    
'org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.AliasBeanTagHandler' depends on legacy  facelet class.  
The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
```

And many other warnings about diferent handlers (like a AliasBeansScopeTagHandler, HtmlInputCalendarTagHandler and so on). How can I avoid this warnings?
I tried to change the artifactId of tomahawk on tomahawk21 or tomahawk20, but it didn't help + it threw this:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name resources.application, locale en
```

UPDATE:
I considered to add the stacktrace, which  was displayed in the case where I tried to use tomahawk20:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name resources.application, locale en
at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1028)
at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.resource.UncompressedResourceHandlerWrapper.getLocalePrefixForLocateResource(UncompressedResourceHandlerWrapper.java:242)
at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.resource.UncompressedResourceHandlerWrapper.createResource(UncompressedResourceHandlerWrapper.java:78)
at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.resource.UncompressedResourceHandlerWrapper.createResource(UncompressedResourceHandlerWrapper.java:61)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagLibrary.getCompositeComponentResource(CompositeComponentTagLibrary.java:155)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before deploy your application on weblogic, the first deploy in under apache tomcat, and try to solve warnings.
" Can't find bundle for base name resources.application, locale en ", if your application wit maven, put 
i18n.properties file to src\main\resources

I uploaded fully configured JSF2.2 project tamplate to github
[JSF frontend](https://github.com/armdev/jsf-frontend)